# Pandas.read_excel from filepath

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some problems opening an excel file from outside the directory in pandas.read_excel

```
import pandas as pd
filepath:"C:\\...\\Worksheet.xlsx"
dataframe=pd.read_excel(filepath)
```

NameError: name 'filepath' is not defined

What is going on? How can I solve this?

Comment: You missed to add an `equals` sign while defining `filepath`. Replace `:` with `=`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to replacing `:` with `=`, you may also need to add `r` before the file path in order for python to read the raw file path. For example you can try:

```
filepath = r'C:\\...\\Worksheet.xlsx'
```